# Save comment.id to another object

Tags: django, database, python-3.x, django-models, django-views

I want to save in my database the comment id which has been commented. For that I have two models: Comentario and Pregunta. Look below:

models.py

```
class Comentario (models.Model):
    titulo = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    texto = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    autor = models.ForeignKey (Perfil, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    fecha_publicacion = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    tag = models.ManyToManyField(Tags, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return (self.titulo)

class Pregunta (models.Model):
    descripcion = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    autor = models.ForeignKey (Perfil, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    fecha_pregunta = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    comentario_preguntado = models.ForeignKey(Comentario, null=True, blank=True, related_name="pregunta_set")

    def __str__(self):
        return (self.descripcion)
```

When a comment is commented I want to save the 'comentario' id as 'comentario_preguntado' id. For that I have created the next view:

views.py

```
 def ComentarioListar2 (request):
     aa=Puesto.objects.filter(nombre_puesto=request.user.nom_puesto).values_list('etiquetas')
     bb=Tags.objects.filter(id__in=aa)
objects=Comentario.objects.filter(tag__in=bb).exclude(autor__id=request.user.id)
     form = preguntaform(request.POST or None)

     if request.method == 'POST' and form.is_valid():
         form.instance.autor = request.user
         form.instance.comentario_preguntado=request.comentario.id
         form.save()
     return render(request, 'home/comentario_listar.html', {'objects': objects, 'form': form})
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [

    url(r'^listar2$', views.ComentarioListar2, name="listar2"),

    ]
```

But I obtain this error "ComentarioListar2() missing 1 required positional argument: 'Comentario_id'"

I do not know how to save in the comentario_preguntado id the id of the comment it is commented (comentario_id).

thank you for your help

Comment: you mean you want to save a comment for a post??

Comment: can you provide code for urls.py ?

Comment: I have added the urls.py for the comentarioListar2. What I want to do is to get comentario.id (when it is commented) and save as comentario_preguntado.id.

Answer (score 0):

Your URL needs to be declared so that the primary key of the model instance can be referred to from the view.

It should be like this:

```
url(r'^listar2/(?P<Comentario_id>[0-9]+)/$', views.ComentarioListar2, name="listar2"),
```

So, an example of the URL would be /listar2/101/. Where 101 is the ID of your Comentario model instance.

Then, you can access it in the view with the function you have defined:

```
def ComentarioListar2 (request, Comentario_id):
                                  ^^^^^^^
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, but what I want to do exactly is to get the comment id which has been commented without changing the .url and template. I have changed the views.py as you can see above.